# Adding personal flags to questions

Tags: feature-request, flagging

From time to time I look through the unanswered questions on the main site, to see if I can contribute on any. Usually I will see a lot of questions that I can't answer (no knowldge / experience / software or hardware prerequisites not met) or that I don't want to answer (to complicated / time consuming / too irrelevant for me). It would be nice if I could flag and filter questions, so that I don't see the same (to me) unanswerable questions over and over. I don't know if that is possible or reasonable, as in principle this would mean saving my personal flag selection for (worst case) every question around. So if it should be reasonable to implement such feature, I would like to have personal flags like the following:

- won't answer, prerequisites not met
- won't answer, too time consuming for me (at the moment?)
- won't answer, too complicated for me
- won't answer, too irrelevant (specialized) in my oppinion
- won't answer, inquirer basically wants me to do all the work for him
- I don't get the question (although this might be covered by a regular flag)
- will probably get to it
- will very likely get to it
- will definitely get to it

Maybe it might also be usefull, if the inquirer sees statistics of peoples pesonal flags on his question, so he gets a clue whether someone is likely to answer his question, or if he can convince someone flgging it "too time consuming" with a bounty ;)

So what do you think will this be doable with reasonable effort?

Comment: I'd flag this one as 'interesting, I'd like to see some other answers to it' - er... - that's like adding to favs. `;)`